# Android app about cookie in WebView

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview

I have a `httpURLConnection` request URL, POST Login request.

And when login success obtain cookies.

I embed a WebView in app now, the WebView is used for loading a connection that can visit after login.

The question is the connection I insert with WebView can't connect.the reason I can find is the cookies don't put in WebView right.

How to put cookies in WebView success?

Comment: Can't you do the URL POST in web view itself using javascript? That way you don't need to share cookies between URLConnection and web view.

Comment: @Krishna let me have a try